# Converting multiple files into excel tables

Tags: r

I have 100 pdf files. These contain tables. I want to convert these files to .xlsx format. Is it possible in r. I have make a list of all these files.

```
library(pdftools)
library(stringr)
library(xlsx)
## Selecting all files in working directory ending with .pdf 
myfiles <- list.files( pattern = "pdf$",  full.names = TRUE)
## Reading pdf files
my_pdfs<-lapply(myfiles,pdf_text)
## Converting pdf to excel files
```

Comment: Is any of this code not working? Your approach (using `list.files` to feed `lapply`) makes sense to me.

Comment: @r2evans I donot know how to convert these to excel

Comment: And knowing as much as we do now, I don't know that we can help much. Does your call to `pdf_text` work as expected? What does `my_pdfs` look like after this? Please provide a small sample of the data with `dput(...)` in order to give us a better idea.